# Lumen 5.4 Trying to install Entrust error "There are no commands defined in the "vendor" namespace"

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am trying to install using Lumen 5.4 but I keep getting this error   `There are no commands defined in the "vendor" namespace.`.

Steps I have taken

1) Add `"zizaco/entrust": "5.2.x-dev"` to composer.json

2) Add `$app->register(Zizaco\Entrust\EntrustServiceProvider::class);` too app.php

3) `composer update`

4) Create this helpers.php file

```
if ( ! function_exists('config_path'))
{
    /**
     * Get the configuration path.
     *
     * @param  string $path
     * @return string
     */
    function config_path($path = '')
    {
        return app()->basePath() . '/config' . ($path ? '/' . $path : $path);
    }
}
```

5) Add this to composer.json

```
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/helpers.php"
        ]
    }
```

6) Comment out `//$this->bladeDirectives();` in EntrustServiceProvider.php

7) Changed the publish function to

```
    $this->publishes([
        -            __DIR__.'/../config/config.php' => config_path('entrust.php'),
        +            __DIR__.'/../config/config.php' => app()->basePath() . '/config/entrust.php',
    ]);
```

8) `composer dump-autoload -o`

9) `php artisan vendor:publish`

Error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function Zizaco\Entrust\config_path() in /Users/API/vendor/zizaco/entrust/src/Entrust/EntrustServiceProvider.php on line 31


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
  Call to undefined function Zizaco\Entrust\config_path()
```

Comment: I would recommend not using Zizaco. That package maintainer has been known to abandon his packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed the error by installing this package and than installing entrust

https://github.com/irazasyed/larasupport