# How to generate API documentation without annotations in the Laravel/lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am not able to generate the API documentation in the Laravel/lumen through composer require Rakutentech/Laravel-request-docs --dev.

If there will any tool available for Automatically generate the documentation in the Laravel/lumen.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow swapnil! have you check [ask] and how to write [mcve]? *"I am not able to generate"* - what are the steps you have taken up to this point? have you installed the package? have you call `php artisan lrd:generate`? it would be best if you can describe the order of things. "something break" is not a very clear description of the problem.

Comment: Yes I have install the package. Main issue with with command php artisan vendor:publish --tag=request-docs-config not working in laravel/lumen.

Comment: could you elaborate more on the "not working" part? did you get any error message? what is the message? is your `config` folder has file named `request-docs.php`?

Comment: It will shows the error ERROR There are no commands defined in the "vendor" namespace

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no [`vendor:publish`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/VendorPublishCommand.php) in lumen. You can check using `php artisan list` and it will show that it lacks `vendor` commands:

```
Available commands:
completion           Dump the shell completion script
help                 Display help for a command
list                 List commands
migrate              Run the database migrations
auth
 auth:clear-resets    Flush expired password reset tokens
cache
 cache:clear          Flush the application cache
....
schedule
 schedule:run         Run the scheduled commands
 schedule:work        Start the schedule worker
schema
 schema:dump          Dump the given database schema
```

You could use several work arounds, such as:

- **Just use Laravel**

  This is the easiest and surefire way to get your `Rakutentech/Laravel-request-docs` gets installed. Lumen was meant to be a lightweight framework, it lacking functionality available in Laravel is to be expected.
- **Install another package**

  You can search on packagist and find at least two alternatives. One that's been sitting for 2 years, [`mr-bug-miner/lumen-doc`](https://packagist.org/packages/mr-bug-miner/lumen-doc). The other one is [`davmixcool/lumen-apidoc-generator`](https://packagist.org/packages/davmixcool/lumen-apidoc-generator)  which been sitting for 4 years. Neither one of the packages looked promising - but you can always try.
- **Installing compatibility package**

  On [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44579627/lumen-5-4-trying-to-install-entrust-error-there-are-no-commands-defined-in-the), someone has asked why they can't publish `zizaco/entrust` packge. It has been answered and the solution was to use [`irazasyed/larasupport`](https://packagist.org/packages/irazasyed/larasupport). There are [other alternatives](https://packagist.org/search/?tags=laravel%20lumen%20support), so pick your choice.
- **Adding your own "compatibility" hacks**

  This is the most cumbersome of all and **I am not endorsing it**. You could for one, copy that `VendorPublishCommand.php` into `app/Console/Commands` and see if it works. Though, I believe you will need to strip the original code a bit - especially that `VendorTagPublished` event.

---

If you have started your research with the error messages, you will have an easier time.

Also, a bit of advice, generally asking for off-site resources is shunned upon. Tread carefully whenever you ask for alternative packages.